# Вывод типа лямбда выражения c параметром по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Без использования опции `-Wpedantic` компилятор с поддержкой c++11 разрешает использовать в лямбда-выражениях значение по умолчанию.

Для такого выражения можно использовать тип `std::function` с указанием типов всех параметров, в том числе и тех, что указаны по умолчанию.

Однако, используя автоматический вывод типов с указанием ключевого слова auto, лямбда выражение получает специфичный тип, например, `main()::<lambda(int)>`, где значения в круглых скобках - типы параметров, передаваемых в это выражение. И эти значения указываются всегда вне зависимости от того, есть ли у них значение по умолчанию (что в общем-то и логично).

Ниже привожу пример кода.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void f1(std::function<int()> lambda)
{
    if (lambda)
    {
        std::cout << lambda() << std::endl;
    }
}

void f2(std::function<int(int)> lambda)
{
    if (lambda)
    {
        std::cout << lambda(1) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda1 = [](int a = 3) -> int
    {
        return a;
    };

    f1(lambda1);
    f2(lambda1);

    std::function<int()> lambda2 = []()
    {
        return 1;
    };

    std::function<int(int)> lambda3 = [](int a)
    {
        return a;
    };

    f1(lambda2);
    //f2(lambda2); // Очевидно несоответствие типов

    //f1(lambda3); // Очевидно несоответствие типов
    f2(lambda3);
}
```

В примере кода тип `main()::<lambda(int)>` приводится к `std::function<int()>`. Мне не хватает знаний для понимания, почему компилятор не ругается на несоответствие типов. Прошу помощи в объяснении.

И связанные вопросы.

Могу ли я явно указать тип, подобный тому, что выводится автоматически?

Могу ли я указать компилятору, чтобы он запрещал подобное приведение типов?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тип объекта замыкания (closure object), порождаемого лямбда-выражением, никак не зависит от параметров лямбды и не определяется ими. Наличие или отсутствие аргументов по умолчанию здесь никакой роли не играет. Каждое лямбда-выражение порождает новый *уникальный* тип - это все, что вам нужно знать о типе объекта замыкания. Даже если два лямбда-выражения полностью идентичны, они все равно получат никак не связанные друг с другом уникальные типы. То, что в вашем примере во внутреннем имени этого типа вы увидели какой-то намек на список параметров - не более чем косметическая особенность используемой вами реализации. При этом то текстовое описание типа объекта замыкания, который вы видите в сообщениях компилятора, не является исчерпывающим описанием фактического типа.

Например, в ответ на

```
auto f1 = [](){};
auto f2 = [](){};
&f1 == &f2;
```

вы получите от GCC диагностическое сообщение вида

```
error: comparison between distinct pointer types 
  'main()::<lambda()>*' and 'main()::<lambda()>*' lacks a cast
```

Как видите, описания типов в кавычках совершенно идентичны. Тем не менее это разные, никак не связанные друг с другом типы.

Так что при работе с лямбда-выражениями никакой речи о "соответствии типов" не может быть вообще: все типы объектов замыкания *уникальны* и никогда ничему не соответствуют.

> почему компилятор не ругается на несоответствие типов

Класс `std::function<>` построен на принципах type erasure, т.е. фактически является более узкоспециализированным аналогом `std::any`. Конструктор этого класса является шаблонным (см. номер 5 [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function)) - в нем вообще нет и быть не может никакой проверки "соответствия типов" на уровне базовой системы типов языка. На уровне базовой системы типов языка этот конструктор может принимать на вход абсолютно *любые* типы.

А какие-либо проверки навешиваются на этот конструктор уже на уровне библиотечной реализации, через техники вроде SFINAE. При инициализации вида `std::function<F> sf = f;` проверяется требование *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)*: объект `f` должен быть *Callable* в качестве функции типа `F`. Проверка этого требования и работает в вашем примере.

Например, объект замыкания `lambda1` является *Callable* и как `int()` и как `int(int)`. Поэтому вы можете использовать его и для инициализации `std::function<int()>`, и для инициализации `std::function<int(int)>`.

> Могу ли я явно указать тип, подобный тому, что выводится автоматически?

Явно - нет. Тип объекта замыкания определяется реализацией и синтаксиса для его явного указания не существует. "Указать" его вы можете только неявно после того, как он уже вывелся - через применение `decltype` к уже существующему объекту замыкания

```
auto f1 = [](){};
decltype(f1) f2 = f1;
```

> Могу ли я указать компилятору, чтобы он запрещал подобное приведение типов?

Компилятор здесь ни при чем. Вы имеете дело с чисто *библиотечной* функциональностью:  реализацией `std::function<>`. Пока вы пользуетесь классом `std::function<>`, он будет вести себя как того требует спецификация языка.

Comment: Очень хороший ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Запрет на указание параметров по-умолчанию в лямбда выражениях [был признан дефектом, и устранен в последующих вариантах стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#974). Так что компиляторы относятся к таким действиям сквозь пальцы. Тип лямбда выражения является анонимным и поэтому явно обратится к нему, или как-то по-другому явно указать его нельзя. У `std::function` есть implicit шаблонный конструктор, который может принимать подходящие объекты лямбда-выражений, так что тут ничего не поделаешь.

Answer (score 1):

1. Компилятор не ругается, поскольку лямбда_функцию можно хранить  в
   обьекте  `std::function`
2. Не можете явно указать тип_ этот тип зависит от реализации и его имя
   известна только компилятору.
3. Никакого приведения типов не выполняется(см. пункт №1), поэтому
   указать не делать того, что не делается, не можете